# GNOME Shell Extension screen margin

Tags: gnome, icons, 21.10, gnome-shell-extension

I am in love with tweaking my shell, and I have a few extensions installed.  One of which is [Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/).
When enabled, my Desktop Icons (Desktop Icons: NEO/NG) shift up.  This makes the top bar overlap the icons when the panel is shown, and I would like to fix this by shifting them back down.

The code that modifies the desktop's margins is in `desktopIconsIntegration.js`.  I don't know what I would change to make the icons go back to their normal position, which is why I'm asking here.

## TL;DR

Extension shifts down desktop icons.

I want this fixed, but don't know how to edit the `desktopIconsIntegration.js` file in the Hide Top Bar extension (linked above).  GNOME 40, Ubuntu 21.10.